# .net website not accessible over network

Tags: .net

Tools : VS2010, MySQL server, IIS - all installed on my local computer.

I published a website and is accessible from my computer. I want to access this from another computer on the same network. That computer can ping my computer but unable to access the website.

I tried following formats in internet explorer :

```
http://127.38.45.121/appb/login.aspx

http://127.38.45.121:80/appb/login.aspx

http://127.38.45.121:8080/appb/login.aspx
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have windows firewall enabled?

Comment: I guess yes. But port 80/8080 still should be accessible, isn't it ? I'll give it a try

Comment: ``ping`` is an unreliable way of testing if you can get to a site on a server. It uses a different port and might be allowed or blocked according to different rules. Either way, it looks like a firewall/network configuration issue.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to browse the site?

Comment: it takes quite a long time and then shows timeout error.

Comment: I would certainly start by looking into a firewall issue.

Comment: Sure. 'll look into it. Unfortunately, I just left work place and will see it tomorrow.Shall keep you posted.

Comment: I tried by switchin on the firewall, enabling port 80 for world wide web (http in) but it didnt help. I turned firewall off and tried - but no success so far.